Is there a security risk to having a privileged init container and a non-privileged container in the same pod?
Imagine that I am running arbitrary containers in a Kubernetes clusters. The contents of these containers is out of my control; they could owned by another team, downloaded from the internet, and contain malicious code. I've locked down the privileges of this container.
However, unfortunately I need to run a privileged init container. Is there any attack vector where the arbitrary container can use this privileged init container to escalate its privilege and do some damage?

You have not stated why you need a privileged container. This sounds very much like a XY-problem to me.
